# How to Extract just the text from a website using Jupyter?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the text of an article from a link but while importing the text I am getting all other links, advertisement links , and image names which I don't need it for my analysis.

```
import re
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize, ngrams
from collections import Counter
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.yahoo.com/news/best-bites-weeknight-meals-cauliflower- 
 120000419.html" #this is the link 
html = request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
raw = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml").get_text()
raw
```

***I am getting this result (copied just some few lines, I get actual text of an article as well but exists in other lines)***:

> window.performance && window.performance.mark &&
>   window.performance.mark(\'PageStart\');Best Bites: Weeknight meals
>   cauliflower vegetable fried rice!function(s,f,p){var
>   a=[],e={_version:"3.6.0",_config:{classPrefix:"",enableClasses:!0,enableJSClass:!0,usePrefixes:!0},_q:[],on:function(e,t){var
>   n=this;setTimeout(function(){t(n[e])},0)},addTest:function(e,t,n){a.push({name:e,fn:t,options:n})},addAsyncTest:function(e){a.push({name:null,fn:e})}},l=function(){};l.prototype=e,l=new
>   l;var c=[];function v(e,t){return typeof e===t}var t="Moz O ms
>   Webkit",u=e._config

I just want to know if there is any way for me to extract just the text of an article, ignoring all these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When BS4 parses a site it creates its own DOM internally as an object.

To access different parts of the DOM we have to use the correct accessors or tags like below

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.yahoo.com/news/best-bites-weeknight-meals-cauliflower-120000419.html" #this is the link
html = request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
parsedHTML = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
readableText = parsedHTML.article.get_text() # <- we got the text from inside the <article> tag 
print(readableText)
```

You were close but you didn't specify which tag you wanted to get_text() from.

Also find() and find_all() are very usefull for finding tags on a page.

Comment: Great solution ! Thank You Definity for the help ! Do you know if there is any other way if the links don't have .html ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. BS4 can parse XML/HTML as far as I know. So the page would HAVE to be HTML or XML in order to use tags to traverse the DOM. But, if you mean pages online then they don't have to end with .html in order for it to be HTML, if you can read it with a browser 99% of the time it will be HTML.